# .where doesn't show results using react-firebase-hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, where-clause

Trying to get query results based on current user id. Which is stored in the documents collection under field "uid".

This is my code:

```js
function Channels() {
  const currentUid = auth.currentUser.uid;
  const query = firestore
    .collection("multitwitch")
    .where("uid", "==", currentUid)
    .orderBy("createdAt");

  const [channels] = useCollectionData(query);

  return (
    <>
      <main>
        <div>
          {channels &&
            channels.map((chan) => (
              <ChannelStrip key={chan.id} channel={chan} />
            ))}
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

function ChannelStrip(props) {
  const { twitchchannel } = props.channel;

  return (
    <>
      <iframe
        src={`https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=${twitchchannel}&parent=localhost&muted=true`}
        height="300"
        width="500"
        allowfullscreen
      ></iframe>
    </>
  );
}
```

When I add `.where` in the query this show **no results**.
But when I remove `.orderBy` it **gives results**.

Why is this?

Also tried to add indexing in firestore:

[image: screenshot of created indexes]

No Luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firestore [queries work based on the existence of indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview) that match exactly with the conditions and ordering of each query. By default Firestore automatically indexes all individual fields of your documents, which works for most simple queries.

If you have both a where clause and an order by on different fields, you will need a composite index on those two fields and such indexes are not automatically created. You will instead have to create the index manually, which is likely what you forgot to do.

There are two ways to do create the missing index:

- If you catch and log errors in your code, the output will contain an error message about the missing index. This error message contains a link to the Firestore console with all information about the missing index pre-populated. So: open that link, click the button, wait until the index is built, and retry the query. This is documentation in [creating a missing index through an error message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#create_a_missing_index_through_an_error_message)
- You can also manually create indexes, as shown in the documentation on [creating indexes in the Firebase console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#use_the_firebase_console)

Comment: Already tried making indexes. eventhough there was no error message in the console log.

Comment: "Already tried making indexes" You might want to edit your question and **show** which index you created that you think will be used for this query.

Comment: You are right. Added a screenshot to the post.

Comment: I don't think that index matches your query. For your query you need an index with two fields: `uid, Ascending` and `createdAt, ascending` (and the `__name__` that is automatically added) in that exact order. There really is no reason why it wouldn't give an error message in that case though, so I recommend also checking  the network tab of your browser to see if any traffic/error shows up there.

Comment: Thank you, that did it. Never knew you had to match your indexes... now I know thank you. Still strange it didnt gave me the usual error in the console...